# Hibernate don't retrieve children but still persist if present?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a legacy hibernate application (using hibernate 3.2.6.ga) where we fetch information similar to the structure below. We have a person who contains several other attributes like address details or bank accounts or transactions.

- Person
- - List of Address Details
- - List of bank accounts
- - List of transactions
- - and many more...

With a hibernate mapping file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="myPkg.Person" table="PERSON" schema="WhatEver" lazy="false">    

        <id name="personId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="PERSON_ID" precision="1" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">some_sequence_generator</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <!-- lazy init is true as only some methods is interested in addressDetails-->
        <bag name="addressDetails" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true">
            <meta attribute="propertyType">java.util.LinkedList</meta>          
            <key>
                <column name="PERSON_ID" precision="10" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="myPkg.Address" />
        </bag>
        ...

        <!-- lazy init is true as a person can have billion transactions -->
        <bag name="transactionDetails" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true">
            <meta attribute="propertyType">java.util.LinkedList</meta>          
            <key>
                <column name="PERSON_ID" precision="10" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="myPkg.transaction" />
        </bag>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

We have several methods to retrieve the persons. Some requires that the child related data be returned as well and some not. So all in the mapping file is set to `lazy=”true”`.

In cases where we are interested in the children right after we return the data we do a `Hibernate.initialize(personObjectJustReturned)` to go and fetch the children as well:

```
Person personInstance = (Person) getHibernateTemplate().get(Person.class, new Long(id));
Hibernate.initialize(personInstance);
```

But the problem comes in with the transactions list as this can become a very large set of data - where a person can have billions of transactions.

What I would like to do is never return transactions with the person object at all.

So I can do one of 2 things:

1. Simply make everyting eagerly loaded in my XML file by setting `lazy=”false”` (apart from my transactions) and don’t do a `Hibernate.initialize(personObjectJustReturned)`. But that would mean that any other method returning data will eagerly fetch the child data as well as all methods in the app is using the same hibernate mapping. Which is not ideal as for example not all methods requires address details. So I will be fetching more data than required on a global scale which is bad practice.
2. Remove the transactions field relationship from my config file so hibernate will not even know about the transactions field when it retrieving a person. This will work perfectly but in cases where we save a person object and that person has newly generated transactions we will have to save the transactions separately. Aka we cannot simply tell hibernate go and save the person object which automatically saves the newly generated transactions as hibernate don't know about the relationship anymore.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option you show can lead to memory consumption problems if you have a lot of children per object.

The best option then, is to load the children fetched by the parent object:

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_detail WHERE person = ?
```

This way you avoid the `Hibernate.initialize(personObjectJustReturned)` and fetch the details more precisely (sorted or more filtered).

Then, to save a new transactionDetail, the `TransactionDetail` object must have the `Person` object set (as the parent) and when saving (the save will be done at the `TransactionDetail`), no error should happen (the foreign keys will avoid orphans).